# $K= \overline{conv(E)}$ iff for every continuous linear functional $f:X\rightarrow \mathbb{R} $ we have $ \sup_{x \in K}f(x)= \sup_{x \in E}f(x)$

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, convex-hulls

We consider $X$ a normed space, $K$ a compact and convex subset of $X$ and $E \subseteq K$. We need to show that the following are equivalent:

- $K= \overline{conv(E)}$
- for every continuous linear functional $f:X\rightarrow \mathbb{R} $ we have $ \sup_{x \in K}f(x)= \sup_{x \in E}f(x)$

Also, by $conv(E)$, we denote the convex hull of $E$, meaning the set of all convex combinations of points in $E$. 
I know that $K = conv(Ext(K))$, by the Krein-Milman theorem, where $Ext(K)$ is the set of the extreme points of $K$. 
I don't know where to go from there. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: For any point in $K$ you can find a point in the convex hull of $E$ arbitrarily close...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Krein Milman theorem does not say only that. It also says that, if $K=\overline{\text{co}}(E)$ for some subset $E$, then $E$ contains the extreme points of $K$. See for example [Murphy](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0125113609)'s approach in appendix A.

So assume the first bullet holds. Fix a functional $f\in X^*$. By our earlier remark it (is necessary and) suffices to show that $\sup_{x\in K}f(x)=\sup_{x\in\text{ext}(K)}f(x)$. Note that since $K$ is compact, this supremum is actually a maximum. Set
$$M=\{y\in K: f(y)=\sup_{x\in K}f(y)\}$$
and therefore $M$ is non-empty. Note that $M$ is a face of $K$, so it contains an extreme point, by the Krein-Milman theorem. But extreme points of a face of $K$ are extreme points in $K$ as well, so $M\cap\text{ext}(K)\neq\emptyset$. Therefore, if $c\in M\cap\text{ext}(K)$ we have that
$$\sup_{x\in K}f(x)=f(c)\leq\sup_{x\in\text{ext}(K)}f(x)$$
and the other inequality is obvious.

For the converse, we use the Hahn-Banach theorem: if $\overline{\text{co}}(E)\neq K$, then find a point $x_0\in K\setminus\overline{\text{co}}(E)$. Since $\overline{\text{co}}(E)$ is a closed subset of $K$, it is compact. It is obviously convex, so by the Hahn-Banach theorem there exists a continuous functional $f$ and a real number $t$ so that
$f(x)<t<f(x_0)$
for all $x\in\overline{\text{co}}(E)$. But then $\sup_{x\in E}f(x)\leq t<f(x_0)\leq\sup_{x\in K}f(x)$, a contradiction to our hypothesis.

Comment: I'm not familiar with "faces", could you please elaborate?

Comment: @GeorgeBerkow A face of $K$ is a subset $C\subset K$ with the property that if $x=ty+(1-t)z\in C$ for some $t\in[0,1]$ and $y,z\in K$ then $y,z\in C$. You can easily verify that the set I described is a face and you can easily prove that an extreme point of a face is an extreme point in the set itself, these are very elementary lemmas. However, check out Murphy's book, you can find these facts proven in appendix A. If you have any problem verifying these claims, I can help you out but please try those first! :)

Comment: Oh now I get it. In my course, we defined that as "an extreme subset of K". Thanks!

Comment: @GeorgeBerkow no problem! If the above answer completely answers your question, please consider accepting it so the post is marked as "answered".

Comment: Of course, but I have one last question: Could you please explain why the set $M$ is a face of K? I've tried proving it, but I'm a bit stuck for some reason.

Comment: @GeorgeBerkow sure, it's easy: suppose that $x=ty+(1-t)z\in M$, so $f(x)$ is equal to the maximum. Since $f$ is linear, this means that $tf(y)+(1-t)f(z)=\text{max}$. Suppose that $f(y)<\max$. Since $f(z)\leq\max$, then we would have strict inequality $tf(x)+(1-t)f(z)<t\max+(1-t)\max=\max$, a contradiction. Likewise if $f(z)<\max$ we get a contradiction, so we must have equality.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It was very easy after all.